# How to content manage a page that makes the edit and config buttons disappear?

Tags: html, css, dotnetnuke

How does one content manage a page that has height and width set to 100% in DotNetNuke??

The full-height style **seems to override the DNN style**, and hence the edit and config buttons disappear or stop working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely need to override the CSS for the ControlBar to have a higher Z Index to ensure it doesn't get hidden.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisHammond, the solution was to make the main div of my new content to -1. I tried what you suggested, namely the opposite: making DNN's code have a higher z-index (say 999999) but this didn't work for some reason.